# htaccess rewrite rule with a number as part of the subdomain name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following which works well for my test website wiki.rehman.website

```
RewriteEngine On

# main rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

But it does not work for my other test subdomain wiki2.rehman.website (notice the "2" in the URL).

```
RewriteEngine On

# main rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^/?wiki2(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

Is there something I should do when numbers are used in the URL?

Comment: What error do you face?

Comment: No error. It simply does not redirect correctly. The same code works for wiki.rehman.website.